# Transition does not go both ways

Tags: html, css

The problem I have is that when I set a:

```
.banner-division2 h2:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 0.6 ease;
    transition: 1s ease;
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    color: #00C8BD;
}
```

It will only transition for the first part of the hover. In other words, once the mouse has exited the "hover" area, it will automatically go back to it's original form - however, I want it to transition ease back into it's original form (it isn't doing this).

Many thanks.

Comment: Remember to mark your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You need to put the `transition` property on the element you want the effect, not on the `:hover`.

Like this

```css
h2 {
  color: blue;
  transition: 1s ease;
}

h2:hover {
  color: red;
}
```

If this not work , try to add the value `all` on the `transition` property

Comment: This is all contained in my answer given 4 minutes before yours. So what value does adding your answer add?

Comment: sorry, i was trying to search for the answer and didn't notice that you already had answered, if you feel unconfortable i can delete.

Comment: I don't feel uncomfortable. Decide by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You have defined the `transition` for the `:hover` state *only*. When not in `:hover`, no `transition` is defined - and ofc, none does happen. So split your rule:

```
.banner-division2 h2 {
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
}
.banner-division2 h2:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);
    transform: scale(1.2);
    color: #00C8BD;
}
```

This way, the transition targets your `h2`, not only your `h2:hover`.